# UITableView mess with the rows content

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to copy only the necessary code to show my problem. I have a tableview with dynamic content. I created a prototype cell and it has a user name and 10 stars (it's a rating page). People in the group are allowed to rate other people. Everything is working ok, but I have a problem when I scroll down. If I rate my first user with 8 stars, when I scroll down then some user that was in the bottom area of the tableview, appears with the rate that I gave to my first user. I know that tableview reuse cells. I tried many things but with no success. Hope someone can help me on that.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let model = users[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RatingCell") as! RatingTableViewCell
        cell.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.playerLabel.text = model.name

        cell.averageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.averageView.layer.borderColor = Color.Gray1.CGColor
        cell.averageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        cell.starsView.userInteractionEnabled = true

        cell.averageLabel.text = "\(user.grade)"

        for i in 0...9 {
            let star = cell.starsView.subviews[i] as! UIImageView
                star.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(starTap)))
            star.userInteractionEnabled = true
            star.tag = i
            star.image = UIImage(named: (i + 1 <= grade ? "star-selected" : "star-empty"))
        }
        return cell
}

func changeRating(sender: UIImageView) {
    let selectedStarIndex = sender.tag
    let cell = sender.superview?.superview?.superview as! RatingTableViewCell
    let model = users[cell.tag]
    let stars = sender.superview?.subviews as! [UIImageView]

    cell.averageLabel.text = "\(selectedStarIndex + 1)"

    for i in 0...9 {
        let imgName = i <= selectedStarIndex ? "star-selected" : "star-empty"
        stars[i].image = UIImage(named: imgName)
    }
}

func starTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    changeRating(gesture.view as! UIImageView)
}
```

Comment: You need to remember which people you rated. Because cells are reusable objects so `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` may return the same cell instance for different indexPath values.

Comment: You should have all of the logic for the rating cell inside your `RatingTableViewCell` class. It doesn't belong in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function.

Comment: I have an array with selected rates. I am using it on cellForRowAtIndexPath. I have a model that is the user[indexPath.row] and I look inside my ratingArr for the user with userId == model.id. I heard that use tag to keep the current index is a bad idea. Maybe thats the problem.

Comment: The problem is on the indexPath.row value. When I scroll down it prints correctly from 1 to 10 (my list has 10 users). If I scroll up slowly it shows the number 2, but it should be 4. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to solve this problem is by updating the model that holds all the information for the uitableviewcell. Whenever a rating is updated fora  particular cell, make sure you reflect that update in the respective object / dictionary in an array. Furthermore, if you have a customuitableviewcell, it might be a good idea to reset the stars in the "prepareForUse" function, so that way when a cell is reused it doesn't use old data.

Answer (score 0):

In your comments, you said that you have an array with selected rates.But you did not show that in your code.

In my opinion, you need record ***indexPath*** too, because ***indexPath.row*** is binding with your rate data(may be ***grade***?).The best way to do so is that @Jay described up.And you should not write the code of configuring cell data and cell's logic in your view controller.If your business logic is complex, you will find that it is a nightmare.^=^